# RecordSet2 mis match with RecordSet DAO.Recordset

Tags: ms-access-2013

## Holiday Database

I need to know how many people in a particular department are off, so new holiday requests can either be "Approved" or "Rejected"

Table
[This is the Table_Add_Holidays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5pfY.png)

Data for Department
[Test Data with 2 departments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kreBv.png)

Data for the Approved
[Just sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4UZV.png)

I used a Query to perform this it worked then after I changed other code elsewhere it stopped working. So I restarted from scratch using the above code and this doesn't work as I thought it would.

I want to filter the data by "Approved" first then
I want to filter by "Department" so I can get a record count of how many people are off in the department

Any help would be appreciated
TIA

---

```
' Dim rstQuery As DAO.Recordset
' Dim rstQuery2 As DAO.Recordset

Dim rstQuery As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rstQuery2 As DAO.Recordset2

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'   I was using a Query but when I tried "Set rstQuery = rstQuery2.OpenRecordset" I had a mis match
'   rstQuery  - was RecordSet
'   rstQuery2 - whilst this was was RecordSet2
'
'    Set rstQuery2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Query_Table_Add_Holidays_CountOff_General]")

Set rstQuery2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Table_Add_Holidays]")

rstQuery2.Filter = "StatusOfRequest = 'Approved'"
FindRecordCount = rstQuery2.RecordCount

rstQuery2.Filter = "Department = '" & oDept & "'"
FindRecordCount = rstQuery2.RecordCount

' Set rstQuery = rstQuery2.OpenRecordset
Set rstQuery = rstQuery2


If rstQuery.EOF Then
    FindRecordCount = 0
Else
    rstQuery.MoveLast
    FindRecordCount = rstQuery.RecordCount
End If

rstQuery.Close

Set rstQuery = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could *DCount*:

```
HolidayCount = DCount("*", "[Table_Add_Holidays]", "StatusOfRequest = 'Approved' And Department = '" & oDept & "'")
```

Comment: Thank you.
I'll give that a go.